# How do I verify PVC pipes have been glued and separate them if they have been?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, pvc, removal

I am replacing an old double sink with a new large single sink plus a disposal.

It seems that the old PVC for the old sink has been glued at each joint. How do I verify PVC has been glued and what is best way to remove old PVC plumbing?

Comment: Smooth thin joints usually glued.  Joints with thick rings with knobs can usually be undone/unscrewed.  Very slight possibility that someone did not use glue, just struck them together, but doubt that, they might come apart with light tapping.

Comment: When installing a new sink like that, its usually best to remove all the old plumbing and start over.

Comment: How about a picture so we can see what you see.

Comment: Post a picture.  Click "Edit" above and paste a clear photo of the old pipework.  I agree with @JPhi1618, glued or not you should replace whatever is easy to replace.  A picture will help determine what's best.

Answer (score 4):

#### If you see nuts like these:

[image: Plastic slip joint nut] [image: Metal slip joint nut]
<sup>Images from Lowes.com, used as example only</sup>

Then that indicates your plumbing is simply screwed together. (Note that you won't see the red (or sometimes translucent white) washer until you've taken the joint apart.) Unscrew the nuts, wiggle the pipes apart, and set the pieces aside. Odds are really good that you'll be able to reuse one of the traps under your new sink.

#### If you see a pipe pushed into another pipe like this:

[image: glued P-trap]
<sup>click to embiggen</sup>

Then your joints are glued. The tell-tale is the purple (usually) residue near the joints - this is the primer that is used for cleaning the parts as part of preparing the joint for gluing. It's not sloppy work - it's supposed to be that way, it helps pass inspection, as the inspector can easily see that primer was used and the joints was properly glued.

In this case, you'll cut the pipes, as you cannot easily and reliably unglue these joints. You can use a hacksaw to cut the pipe - be sure to make a nice, square cut so you've got a good end to attach the new plumbing to. Or, you can use a pipe cutter which will spin around the pipe multiple times making a very clean cut for you.

When you make your cuts, be sure to leave as much sticking out from the wall as possible - you'll need that stub-out to attach the new P-Trap to. If you cut it too short, you'll be asking us how to fix that problem. You can always cut it shorter later if you discover it's too long, but that's a *much* easier problem to solve than trying to make it longer because you cut it flush to the wall.

If you've got additional questions about cutting the pipes, please search this site, as I'm sure there are a number of questions about it here.